# Copy output of custom target in one CSPROJ into another CSPROJ

Tags: c#, msbuild, game-development, msbuild-target

So I'm developing a game engine framework for myself in C#/.NET and I have been trying to simplify building shader files (the rendering engine consumes SPIR-V files, which I want to generate from GLSL source).
My current approach has been to use a custom .targets file which is imported into a CSPROJ, and that file defines a custom target like this:

```
<Target
    Name="Vert"
    AfterTargets="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)%(VertShader.RelativeDir)"/>
    <Exec Command='"$(ENGINE_ROOT)\tools\glslang\windows-x64\glslangValidator.exe" -V %(VertShader.Identity) %(VertShader.OptLevel) -o $(OutputPath)%(VertShader.Identity).spv'></Exec>
</Target>
```

The general idea behind this is it takes VertShader items, runs the .vert file through glslang, and spits the output .vert.spv file into the build output directory.
This works great, *almost*.

The problem is, if I have Project A that has a bunch of shaders, and then Project B which has a reference to Project A, I want to copy the .vert.spv shaders that Project A generates into the build output directory of Project B, but I haven't had much luck wrangling the target syntax to do what I want.

Is there any way I can get this working the way I'm describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I actually did manage to figure it out on my own I think, adding an answer in case it's helpful to anyone else.
Adding this to my .targets file appears to allow them to be copied to any dependent project. I *believe* this is basically registering all of the files I'm creating with a list of files that MSBuild copies to whatever the current build output directory is (which causes them to get copied to any project that references this one)

```
<Target
    Name="IncludeVert"
    BeforeTargets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems">
    <ItemGroup>
        <CompiledVerts Include="@(VertShader -> '$(OutputPath)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).vert.spv' )">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <TargetPath>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).vert.spv</TargetPath>
        </CompiledVerts>
        <AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath Include="@(CompiledVerts->'%(FullPath)')"  />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem correctly, but if you want your .vert.spv copied to another folder use File.Copy()

Comment: The gist is I need Project A to contain some shader files, and what I *want* is for Project B to be able to reference Project A and have those shader files compiled and placed into its own output directory alongside the EXE when I build.